# Which game is this six-sided die with two sets of runic-looking plus, minus and empty sides from?

Tags: identify-this-game

I have just received this die as an extra gift in a pack of games I bought online, but I really cannot identify where is this from?

The other 3 sides are equal to the 3 visible, overall two have that cross, two that line and two have no symbol.

[image]

Comment: It might help people to know what is on the other side as well?  are all 6 sides different?

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about that, I'll edit the question now.

Comment: my first thought is the markings are a "plus" and "minus" symbol.  googling dice with plus and minus signs you find dice matching that pattern.

Comment: It could also be a 0, 1, 2 for the symbols but I think the +, -, 0 make more sense.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These are fudge or [fate dice](https://www.pngitem.com/middle/hxTTbxo_fate-dice-set-4d6-ancient-beige-black-data/) used for the [fudge role playing game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fudge_(role-playing_game_system)).

> Fudge uses customized "Fudge dice" which have an equal number of plus, minus and blank sides. A number of these dice are rolled, usually four at a time ("4dF" in Fudge dice notation), and for every plus side that comes up the result of using the Trait is considered one step higher (e.g. from Fair to Good) and for every minus side that comes up the result is considered one step lower. The goal is to match or surpass the difficulty level, also on the adjective scale, of the test. Thus, a Good attribute is considered to be Great if the player were to roll two plus sides, one minus side, and one blank—the minus side cancels out one of the plus sides and the remaining plus side raises the result by one step. The same Good attribute would be considered Poor if you were to roll three minus sides and one blank. The same dice roll can be achieved with six-sided dice, treating a 1 or 2 as [−], a 3-4 as [ ] and a 5-6 as [+].

[image]

Note: the symbols in the corners are +, - and 0.

Answer (score 21):

[image]

Those are called fate or fudge dice, and they have 2 blank sides, 2 sides with a + and two sides with a -. That particular die does not come from any specific game, it's instead the "Ancient Fate Dice" set made by [Q Workshop](https://q-workshop.com/), though I can't seem to find their fate/fudge dice on their website, I have found amazon.com offerings of the [same design in different colors](https://www.amazon.ca/Antique-Fudge-Dice-White-Black/dp/B004RORVSE).

Many games use these dice, the one I am most familiar with is [Tales of the Arabian Nights](https://www.zmangames.com/en/products/tales-arabian-nights/) by Z-Man Games, though the most well known use for them is probably the RPG systems that share their names with the dice used in it [Fudge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fudge_(role-playing_game_system)) and [Fate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate_(role-playing_game_system)).

Comment: A note of warning: while Q Workshop produces some *gorgeous* dice sets, at least in the past they have used ridiculously insecure user account practices (storing and sending one’s password in plaintext). The website seems to have gotten a redesign since I last shopped there, so hopefully that’s changed, but consider trying to avoid sending them any sensitive information that you can’t easily change.